# Logging level DEBUG inside a body of another log level INFO

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, glassfish, slf4j, payara

We have a JavaEE EAR application that's deployed on **Payara 4.1.2.1**. This application have dependency on:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What's happening is that the **server.log** are fully increase with **DEBUG** log message inside a body of **INFO** log message for a lot of frameworks and librarys that's used by our applcation, like: **org.jose4j.jws**, **apache.axis**. This begun happening after we change the version of **slf4j-log4j12**.

```
[2018-10-08T08:03:18.712-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598712] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.712 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactoryFactory - JWE key management algorithms: [RSA1_5, RSA-OAEP, RSA-OAEP-256, dir, A128KW, A192KW, A256KW, ECDH-ES, ECDH-ES+A128KW, ECDH-ES+A192KW, ECDH-ES+A256KW, PBES2-HS256+A128KW, PBES2-HS384+A192KW, PBES2-HS512+A256KW, A128GCMKW, A192GCMKW, A256GCMKW]
]]

[2018-10-08T08:03:18.720-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598720] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.720 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.j.j.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm - org.jose4j.jwe.AesCbcHmacSha2ContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes128CbcHmacSha256@6f7dada6 registered for enc algorithm A128CBC-HS256
]]

[2018-10-08T08:03:18.722-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598722] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.722 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.j.j.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm - org.jose4j.jwe.AesCbcHmacSha2ContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes192CbcHmacSha384@13aa41bd registered for enc algorithm A192CBC-HS384
]]

[2018-10-08T08:03:18.725-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598725] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.725 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.j.j.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm - org.jose4j.jwe.AesCbcHmacSha2ContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes256CbcHmacSha512@52ef3d54 registered for enc algorithm A256CBC-HS512
]]

[2018-10-08T08:03:18.730-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598730] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.730 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.j.j.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm - org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes128Gcm@66fbe55 registered for enc algorithm A128GCM
]]

[2018-10-08T08:03:18.733-0300] [Payara 4.1] [INFORMA��ES] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=75 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1538996598733] [levelValue: 800] [[
  08:03:18.732 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG o.j.j.AlgorithmFactory->ContentEncryptionAlgorithm - org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm$Aes192Gcm@18560c6b registered for enc algorithm A192GCM
]]
```

We already tried to change some things on log levels **Logger Settings** -> **Log Levels** in Payara admin interface, but these logs still being recorded.

Any suggests are welcome.